# Magento 2: How to filter orders by order items

Tags: magento2, php, orders, collection, filter

In magento 1, I was able to filter orders by the following:

```
$orderitem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
$orderitem->addFieldToFilter('name',array('like'=>'%'.$value.'%'));  
$ids =array();
foreach($orderitem as $item){
  $ids[] = $item->getOrderId(); //  sales_flat_order_item.order_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id
}
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("entity_id",array("in",$ids));
return $this;
```

How would I achieve this in Magento 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

You need to think more like class, name space and functions so what you like have to go inside a function, in one of your modules:

also try to learn about ordercollectionfactory. here is an example

```
<?php

namespace 'moduleNameSpace';
class ModelClass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')

}
   public function getmyorderdetails(array $filters = [])
    { $orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();
        $orderitem=$orders->addFieldToFilter(('name',$filters);

        $ids =array();
        foreach($orderitem as $item){
            $ids[] = $item->getOrderId();
        }
        $orders->addFieldToFilter("entity_id",array("in",$ids));
     return $this->orderCollectionFactory;
}
}
```